# Using placeholder in XML file to placing the value from a properties file

Tags: java, xml, spring, properties, xml-configuration

I would like to have palceholder in my xml file which places the value from a properties file.

The **SystemProperty.xml** file is just a global system configuration file, not any kind of spring configuration, which looks like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PropertyList>
    <Property>
        <Name>CommandTimeout</Name>
        <Value>60</Value>
        <Description>Setting the timeout(in seconds)</Description>
        <DefaultValue></DefaultValue>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Name>Address</Name>
        <Value>${server.IP}</Value>
        <Description>ip:port</Description>
        <DefaultValue></DefaultValue>
    </Property>
</PropertyList>
```

It is using by XMLConfiguration bean to loading in

```
<bean
    id="xmlConfiguration"
    class="org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration"
    lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
        <value>SystemProperty.xml</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="expressionEngine">
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.tree.xpath.XPathExpressionEngine" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

And use it in my code as below

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("xmlConfiguration")
XMLConfiguration            xmlConfiguration;
```

However, the ***${server.IP}*** placeholder doesn't work any.

In the other hand, for spring configuration xml, I can do that. For example, I have a **Scheduler.xml** which is Quartz configuration xml as below.

```
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource">PostgreSQLQuartzDataSource</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.PostgreSQLQuartzDataSource.driver">org.postgresql.Driver</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.PostgreSQLQuartzDataSource.URL">jdbc:postgresql://${scheduler.db.host}:${scheduler.db.port}/${scheduler.db.database}</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.PostgreSQLQuartzDataSource.user">${scheduler.db.username}</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.PostgreSQLQuartzDataSource.password">${scheduler.db.password}</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.PostgreSQLQuartzDataSource.maxConnections">10</prop>
                ...
        </props>
    </property>
```

And **application.properties** file as below

```
# Quartz scheduler database resource
scheduler.db.host=127.0.0.1
scheduler.db.port=5432
scheduler.db.database=scheduler
scheduler.db.username=test
scheduler.db.password=test

# Server settings
server.IP=192.168.111.12
```

By using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean:

```
<bean
    id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And of cause import the Scheduler.xml in SpringApplication-context.xml

```
<import resource="Scheduler.xml" />
```

Is it possible to import properties into a normal XML file for using placeholder? Can I set up it in XMLConfiguration or any other ways?

Any help is appreciated.